# Elasticsearch compound query with a nullable or valuedspecific term?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'd like to search with a term with some values and also allow default nullable value. Trying to write codes like below, but seems not working.

```
new BoolQueryBuilder().should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(esPropertyName, values))
            .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(esPropertyName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out a way:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(esPropertyName, values))
            .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(esPropertyName)));
```